# How to change to production environment

Tags: apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox to relay push notification messages.

And no matter what I do, I seem to be stuck in the development environment.

What do I need to do to change it to production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#How_QuickBlox_Push_Notifications_work

```
#ifndef DEBUG
    [QBSettings useProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:YES];
#endif
```

Comment: I basically need to set it to "NO" otherwise its stuck in development

Comment: I uploaded my production certificate, my alert view says the push was sent successfully, yet the recepient didnt receive the push notification do you know why that could happen ?

Comment: which environment you use in your app and which in admin panel?